# Meld: Change color scheme

Tags: meld

I'm using win10 and dark mode.

A conflict is highlighted in blue, and the details in it are highlighted in a lighter blue.

I'd like to change all these colors.

I tried [this meld.css](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Meld/DarkThemes), but it changed nothing.

---

I think I found it.

First, the dir gtksourceview-3.0 doesn't seem to be in use.

In my chosen scheme: meld-dark.xml

The background in

```
<style name="meld:replace" background="#000000" foreground="#1d59d6" line-background="#0053a6"/>
```

sets the conflict background.

The background in

```
<style name="meld:inline" background="#24527e"/>
```

sets the detail color.