# Meld: wrap lines, keep whole words

Tags: meld

Meld has a line wrap option.

How do I tell it to keep words whole?

---

A few more small things:

- Is there a way to change the keyboard shortcuts?
- Undo undoes one character at the time. That's not a common behavior.
- Can I change the whole color scheme and not just what I pointed out here:
  [Meld: Change color scheme](https://superuser.com/questions/1716105/meld-change-color-scheme)
- Since Meld is currently my default tool, it means that the authors did a good job. However, since merging involves text editing, I think they should have started from a conventional editor rather than writing one from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Meld Preference => Editor first tick on  "Enable text wrapping". Then just below it there is another checkbox for "Do Not Split Word over two lines". Tick that and your problem will be solved.